# Google play services update to 9.0.0 even though current version is 9.2.1

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, gradle, google-authentication

I'm having an issue with this google play services plugin. It is telling me to update from the current version to a previous one.  I have looked at other threads on here and they all say to put the plugin at the end of the app based gradle, which I already did, but I am still getting the error.

Here is my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mikediloreto.findingrestaurants">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is the app-based gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mikediloreto.findingrestaurants"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the project based build gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please let me know if you would like me to include any other code.

Comment: Your build gradle file ?

Comment: @androidXP I just added it

Answer (score 1):

First of all here is something u shouldnt do

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
```

its a good practice to have on global variable for libs having the same versions
then u could do something like

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$google_ver"
```

might be that 11.xxx nd 9.xxx versions r cosing the trouble. Try using 11.0.4 instead of 9.2.1